# PayPal Express checkout SALUTATION not received in response

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal Express checkout for payment. I need the SALUTATION of the user along with other shipping details. But it seems that only FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME are got from the response. What should be done to get the SALUTATION in the response as well.

This is the response got from GetExpressCheckoutDetails

> TOKEN:EC%2d9F317807RE7947807
>   BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS:0
>   CHECKOUTSTATUS:PaymentActionCompleted
>   TIMESTAMP:2016%2d05%2d12T11%3a54%3a16Z
>   CORRELATIONID:c50a6ba8b3002
>   ACK:Success
>   VERSION:93
>   BUILD:000000
>   EMAIL:nihal%40gmail%2ecom
>   PAYERID:2CLDDRMSKLDMA
>   PAYERSTATUS:unverified
>   FIRSTNAME:Nihal
>   LASTNAME:Mohammad
>   COUNTRYCODE:IN
>   SHIPTONAME:Nihal
>   SHIPTOSTREET:Chakkorathukulam
>   SHIPTOSTREET2:Nadakkavu
>   SHIPTOCITY:Calicut
>   SHIPTOSTATE:KOZHIKODE
>   SHIPTOZIP:670006
>   SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE:IN
>   SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME:India
>   ADDRESSSTATUS:Unconfirmed
>   CURRENCYCODE:USD
>   AMT:10%2e00
>   SHIPPINGAMT:0%2e00
>   HANDLINGAMT:0%2e00
>   TAXAMT:0%2e00
>   INSURANCEAMT:0%2e00
>   SHIPDISCAMT:0%2e00
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE:USD
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT:10%2e00
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT:0%2e00
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT:0%2e00
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT:0%2e00
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT:0%2e00
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT:0%2e00
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID:2KR64654T7820071F
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED:false
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME:Nihal
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET:Chakkorathukulam
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2:Nadakkavu
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY:Calicut
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE:KOZHIKODE
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP:670006
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE:IN
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME:India
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS:Unconfirmed
>   PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID:2KR64654T7820071F
>   PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE:0

In PayPal documentation they say it is available in response.
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrSD6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple problem. I was using the merchant account for US region. And the US region does not need the SALUTATION part for their address. That was why the response was not returning the salutation part i guess.